# are banana/orange/etc. questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

I own a banana pi which I have chosen over RPi for several reasons (good lcd support, wifi with AP mode). When looking for online resources I often find relevant information on RPi sites.

I suppose this site would benefit from questions and answers which apply to both RPi and banana pi. But what about banana-specific questions? Surely banana pi has a smaller community, perhaps not big enough to have a separate SE site. Could we allow such questions here?

Comment: by the way, even the old versions of the Pi support LCD and AP mode - this depends much more on the LCD and wifi hardware you are using